# Two Vertices of a square

Tags: geometry

Being (-2, 4) and B (3, -1) consecutive vertices of a square, determine the other two vertices
How to solve this only algebraically?

Would point-to-point distance (relative position between points and circumference) help?

Comment: It's simpler than that.  Once you have two vertices $P(x, y)$ and $Q(x+r, y+s)$ of a square, you can get the other two vertices, by adding $\pm s$ and $\pm r$ to the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$.  To see exactly how this works, try an example square: say, $(2, 2), (3, 5), (6, 4), (5, 1)$.  The basis is that two perpendicular lines have slopes that multiply to $-1$, and (as you have evidently figured out), the sides have the same length.

Comment: It seems to me that given one side of a square, there would be two ways to complete the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We find the  coordianates of the other two vertices considering three facts.

1) The midpoints of the diagonals should match.

2) The adjecent sides should be perpendicular.

3) The adjacent sides should have the same length.

With these properties we have a system of four eqautions $$ a+3= c-2, d+4=b-1$$ and

$$ d+1=c-3, (c-3)^2+(d+1)^2 = 50$$ where the two missing vertices are $$ (a,b), (c,d)$$

After solving we get the other vertices to be either $$(8,4), (3,9)$$
 or $$(-7,-1), (-2,-6)$$
Thus we have two squares with the given data.

Comment: Please show me the system

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi  I have included the system in my edit.